# Blog with subscription option to send emails on new blog entry

Tags: nodes, notifications

I'm working with Drupal 7. How do I setup 'Subscription' option for my blog so that upon every New Entry of the blog, an email is sent out to the subscribers?

Comment: Some helpful pages: https://groups.drupal.org/node/15928 and https://www.drupal.org/node/645108

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use the [MailChimp](http://drupal.org/project/mailchimp) module but requires the extra step of registering on [MailChimp.com](https://mailchimp.com/signup/).

> This module provides integration with the MailChimp email delivery
>   service. While tools for sending email from your own server, like
>   SimpleNews, are great, they lack the sophistication and ease of use of
>   dedicated email providers like MailChimp. Other players in this field
>   are Constant Contact and Campaign Monitor.

Answer (score 1):

There are several modules that will provide this for you.

Check out [Notifications](http://drupal.org/project/notifications) first, as it may do what you need. There is also [Notify](http://drupal.org/project/notify) and [Subscriptions](http://drupal.org/project/subscriptions).

Answer (score 0):

Try [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules)

One of the highly flexible module i have ever came across.

The rules module allows site administrators to define conditionally executed actions based on occurring events

Answer (score 0):

I made a module which solves this using mailchimp:
[mailchimp_subscriptions](https://drupal.org/sandbox/merge/2076979).

Feedback is welcome! Planning to promote it to a full module soon.